# Setting LibreOffice Menus Font Size (on Buster)

Tags: buster

My current LibreOffice version is 6.1.5.2.

Does anyone have a way to increase the size of the fonts used in the menus?

How it looks at 1080p:

[image: How it looks at 1080p. No (longer any) option to re-scale app fonts. Menu font does not match regular desktop font.]

Comparison of sizes:

[image: LibreOffice font size compared with other sizes]